# Can't access public properties of my Class

Tags: actionscript-3, class, custom-component

I'm still learning about object oriented programming...

I made my own simple button class to do horizontal buttons lists. I works fine, but...

```
package as3Classes {

import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import fl.motion.MotionEvent;
import flash.text.TextFormat;

public class simpleButton extends MovieClip {

    //var nome:String = new String();
    var sub:Sprite = new Sprite();
    public var realce:Sprite = new Sprite();
    public var titulo:String;

    public function simpleButton(nomeId:String, texto:String) {
        this.name = nomeId;
        this.titulo = texto;
        this.useHandCursor = true;
        this.buttonMode = true;
        this.mouseChildren = false;
        var txtf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        txtf.font = "Arial";
        var txt:TextField = new TextField();
        txt.wordWrap = false;
        txt.multiline = false;
        txt.text = texto;
        txt.setTextFormat(txtf);
        txt.width = txt.textWidth+4;
        txt.height = 22;
        txt.x = 4;
        txt.y = 2;
        txt.cacheAsBitmap = true;
        var fundo:Sprite = new Sprite();
        fundo.graphics.beginFill(0xCCCCCC);
        fundo.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, txt.width+8, 22);
        fundo.graphics.endFill();
        //var realce:Sprite = new Sprite();
        this.realce.graphics.beginFill(0x00CC00);
        this.realce.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, txt.width+8, 22);
        this.realce.graphics.endFill();
        this.sub.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
        this.sub.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, txt.width+8, 2);
        this.sub.graphics.endFill();
        this.addChild(fundo);
        this.addChild(this.realce);
        this.addChild(this.sub);
        this.addChild(txt);
        this.sub.alpha = 0;
        this.sub.y = 22;
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseover);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseout);
    }

    private function mouseover(e:MouseEvent){
        sub.alpha = 1;
    }
    private function mouseout(e:MouseEvent){
        sub.alpha = 0;
    }

}
```

}

... when I try to access the "titulo" or set "realce" as alpha=1 (to display it as clicked) it returns undefined. I can only set or read proprieties inherited, as the name, alpha, etc. What is my conceptual mistake?

Comment: Please show code where you're trying to access the public properties.

Comment: Are you importing "as3Classes.*" in the class where you are trying to access these properties? I don't think I need to mention this, but you do need to instantiate the class as well. You can't access these properties via simpleButton.titulo.

Comment: As an afterthought, I noticed you are doing two things incorrectly in this class. All Class names should be capitalized. Package, variable, and function names should follow traditional camelcase, but Class names should always be capitalized and then follow camelcase. You also should avoid instantiating objects in global space (`sub = new Sprite()`). For public/private/protected vars, instantiate them in the constructor instead.

Comment: I'm creating a new instance (var btn:simpleButton = new simpleButton(categ.SubcategoryID, categ.SubcategoryName);) addChild and a listener. Than, in the event handler, e.target.name works, but e.target.titulo don't, neither e.target.realce.alpha.

Comment: Conceptually there's no mistake. Try tracing the nomeId and texto in the constructor to make sure those values are not empty.

Comment: In your event handler, trace if e.target is actually a simpleButton, `if (e.target is simpleButton) ...` if yes, then it should work, otherwise you have to search in parent list of that e.target until you'll either hit stage, null or simpleButton object. `var p:DisplayObject=e.target; while ((p.parent)&&!(p.parent==stage)) { if (p is simpleButton) break; p=p.parent; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! I found a way to avoid this issue: Since (as it seams) I can't access the internal public objects of "simpleButton" by display objects list, I create a private object (btns:Object) in the root of the main class (can be seen everywhere) and add the simpleButtons simultaneously as adding at display. The name is the same, so I can change the realce.alpha by btns and it will reflect in the display.

This is bizarre, because the e.target leads to the child instead of the object itself!

If somebody knows a better way, please let me know.